# Non data hungry models for prediction

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, predictive-models, data-mining

I have a dataset of customer transactions containing revenue, customer id, region, product category, product id, support team, date of trqnsaction etc.

I intend to use buy till you die models for predicting customer churn, customer lifetime value and future number of transactions. These models use probability distributions such as poisson, gamma etc to make predictions

Though the above model works fine when i keep the level of analysis at customer level, but our business is not able to act on the predictions because they may not know this customer is from which region, which product they bought and who is the support team responsible for this customer.

Therefore, in order to make to actionable for my support team to follow up, we need to drill down to the level product id.

Meaning, the team can only act/follow up on predictions if they know the customer id, region,support team, product category and product id.

So, there is need to run my analysis at the granular level (and not at high level like customer). This results in reduction of records and narrow subsets of data is fed into btyd models (for each combination of customer id, region, support team, product id)

So, if Apple is our customer (with 1000 records), after all subdivisions results in 20-30 subsets with data size of 10 to 60 etc.

So, now if I feed these subsets (instead of 1000 records data) to btyd models, would it make reliable predictions? (as it is probabilistic modelling)

Though btyd model seems the right fit for solving the problem, how can I address this issue and is there any other alternative modelling approaches or assumptions that we can take to tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you explain btyd?

Comment: Buy Till you die models uses probability distribution for predicting future purchase count, customer churn probability and customer lifetime value. Here is a useful link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy_Till_you_Die

Comment: Can't you use a single model, trained on all data that uses customer ID, etc as features so can make customer-specific predictions? In linear regression, you could use interactions with the customer ID dummies or hierarchical regression.

Comment: I don't have labels for linear regression

Comment: How do you expect to do supervised learning without labels?

Comment: Yes, that's why I felt btyd models are good for my usecase (didn't try other methods like hierarchical regression). Also, I don't know about that

Comment: So, am I right to understand then that no model can help (probabilistic or traditional ML) when there is little data (like my usecase above). So, prediction cam never ever be done (reliably)

Comment: Do you have any labels? // A lack of labels is a separate issue from having labels but just not having many points.

Comment: No, I don't have labels. But if no other option, then I have to use some rule based approach to come up with labels...Like if customer didn't purchase in last 1 year, he is churned etc

Comment: in my case, as of now there is no labels and also few data points (if I create subsets of data)